# Allow only one copy of an app to run - without programming or third party software

Tags: windows

Windows. I want to allow to run only one copy of an app (for one user or for the whole computer - no matter). Without programming (using mutexes or something) - I have no access to source code. But scripts like Power Shell, or batch files, or rules in security policies are allowed, as well as registry editing.

So the scenario can be looked like this:

1. user runs an app,
2. user tries to run an app again, while the first copy is still running, but nothing happens.

It is not some type of security requirements, but just for convenience. I don't exactly know - perhaps the app uses some shared data, and the second copy just rewrites it. They just requested from me to allow only one copy to run in some administrative way.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What you want isn’t possible without the source code to the application itself

Comment: Which app(s)? All of them? A few specific apps?

Comment: to all: I added also possibility to use batch files

Comment: @music2myear a specific app, so I know its location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround to making an application single instance: Make a script that detects if the app is running, and do nothing if it is.

In a text editor, copy the following script and save it as a batch file, substituting the application's name for Firefox.

```
@echo off
tasklist | findstr "firefox.exe"
if %errorlevel% equ 0 goto running
if %errorlevel% equ 1 start " " "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
exit

:running
exit
```

Then make a shortcut to the .bat file, open the shortcut's properties, and set *Run* to *Minimized* to avoid seeing the CMD prompt.

Of course, a user *could* just run the application itself, creating a second instance.

BTW, there is one issue with this script I would appreciate help fixing: if the app is minimized, using that shortcut does *not* bring it into focus. I tried using [SendKeys()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709474/sendkeys-from-command-prompt) to the app, but that failed to raise it.

Comment: Thank you. I tried, and it works. It can be a way for our clients. Another ways through Windows Policies and Task Scheduler are more complicated, I think. And I know also how to do it through custom .exe launcher and custom installer, but it is even more complicated. So this batch file is a good compromise.