# Windows Explorer only in one instance

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Is it possible to configure the Windows Explorer to only open in one instance? Sometimes the Explorer is already open and after I download something and then open the download location from the browser it opens another Explorer instance, but since Explorer has tabs now it doesn't make sense that it doesn't just open another tab. So, can I "force" the Explorer to open (new) tabs instead of new instances?

Comment: Opening in a new tab or new instance is a property of the App.  Explorer does not offer this setting so far as I know

Comment: It is possible to make any *external* application open in a single instance by use of a script and shortcut to it, https://superuser.com/questions/1717920/allow-only-one-copy-of-an-app-to-run-without-programming-or-third-party-softwa, but *not* Explorer, which is built into the Windows OS.

Comment: @John I understand that opening a new instance is the property of the app, but I thought that Explorer might intervene by "saying" "nope, it's already open, here's a new tab instead"...but well if it's not possible then it's not possible

Comment: It is not possible in the case of Explorer